# SSRS expression - remove line breaks when field contains no data

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report that is a calendar, and it shows each persons different activity for each day. I currently do this via `.vbcrlf` to create the line break.

What I would like to do is only return a line break when there is data in the specific value.

My current expression is:

```
=Fields!DayOfMonth.Value 
        & Constants.vbcrlf 
        & Constants.vbcrlf 
        & Fields!Shift.Value 
        & Constants.vbcrlf 
        & Fields!OT.Value 
        & Constants.vbcrlf 
        & Fields!Holiday.Value 
        & Constants.vbcrlf 
        & Fields!AbsenceType.Value 
        & Constants.vbcrlf 
        & Fields!ClockIn.Value
```

So if there is no Holiday I would like to remove that line and the break meaning `Absence` and `In/Out` would move up the text box. I've tried using `isNothing` but cant get the syntax right.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sees the data as NULL values, which can alter the way it treats text.

You can use `iif(isnothing(Field!Thing.Value), "", Constants.vbcrlf & Field!Thing.Value)` around each one to replace null values with blanks.

There may be a more elegant solution available.

Comment: Specifically, wouldn't [GPH](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2250361/gph) want: `iif(isnothing(Field!Thing.Value), "", Constants.vbcrlf & Field!Thing.Value)`, so a line break is included when the value itself **is** being returned?

Comment: I was thinking that you can keep the vbcrlf in, just replace the fields with blanks when they're empty.

Comment: The problem then is that it won't give the desired behaviour - as I understand the question, [GPH](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2250361/gph) wants to suppress the empty lines when a value is not present for whatever would otherwise have gone on that line.

Comment: @BishNaboB - this seems like what I'm after. Don't suppose you know how i can do multiple iffs?

Comment: @GPH You can do it like `=iif(isnothing(Field!Thing1.Value), "", Constants.vbcrlf & Field!Thing1.Value) & iif(isnothing(Field!Thing2.Value), "", Constants.vbcrlf & Field!Thing2.Value) & iif(isnothing(Field!Thing3.Value), "", Constants.vbcrlf & Field!Thing3.Value)`

Comment: @BishNaboB yeah just got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax which worked for me in VS 2017 with SQL Server Data Tools:

```
=IIf(Fields!Holiday.Value Is "", "", Fields!Holiday.Value + Environment.NewLine)
+ IIf(Fields!AbsenceType.Value Is "", "", Fields!AbsenceType.Value + Environment.NewLine)
```

Code is pretty much self explanatory - if there is no value for Holiday, result is empty string or else if it has value, show value and line break. For latest syntax of any function, just refer to the examples given in the Expression window.